# How can I crop closed SVG paths to produce open paths?

Tags: svg, graphics, bezier, vector-graphics

I asked this question on the graphic design board, and it sounds like this may be more of a programming question than a visual one: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138458/crop-closed-paths-into-open-paths?noredirect=1#comment206864_138458

I'll cross post the content here, since the question is the same, but I'm specifically interested in whether there is an existing solution for this, or if it can be easily scripted. If so, what would be the proper approach?

---

In a few operations, how can I crop closed paths and have the result be a set of open paths? It's important that the solution be as few operations as possible, and not rely on point and click. (I'm looking for something scalable to perform operations on very complex map images.)

Someone asked the same question here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Inkscape/comments/75xjfa/intersection_with_open_paths_or_equivalent/ and I'm working with essentially the same objective. (Motion control systems.)

Here's a very simple example of the objects I'm starting with:
[image: start]

The orange area is a closed path that I want to crop to, and the black lines are a bunch of closed paths that I want to be cropped. This is what I want the result to look like:

[image: end]

The lines *must* be open in the final result. That is, each line is just that - a line with no fill. (Ideally, they'd keep the stroke I've set initially, but not required.)

It's important that this solution applies to much more complex scenarios too. For example, I'd want to crop the lines in this example down to the purple areas:

[image: more complex example]

The images I'm working with are extremely large, and can have thousands of islands to crop out. (Point and click with a mouse to delete paths won't work...)

I'm open to using any software available, but I'd prefer something open source / scriptable. Illustrator or Inkscape would do.

Comment: add a clipPath to clip out everything outside the region you want to be visible.

Comment: That would only produce the visual result, not the actual paths. Is there a way to “flatten” this clip region?

Comment: What you want is a boolean shape operation. Specifically, you want the intersection of your path and clipping shapes. So that involves finding all path/shape intersections, cutting the path at each and everyone one of those points, and then discarding anything that's not inside your clipping shape(s). Is that a lot of work? Sure is, because SVG has nothing built in for that, so you'll want to do some searching for a library that does that for you. For example, Paper.js has a [pretty solid boolean shape operation](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/) built in.